# OOP Architecture Insecurity: Hierarchical Object References

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having a, I think, basic OOP question about how I should handly relationships between objects in my code. 
I'm writing a tool that stores some hierarchical information and I see two options how I can implement that. I'll give some (simplified) examples to support my thought process.

In the first idea, I will instantiate child elements with information about their parent (their hosting container, so to say). Then the child elements themselves will be responsible for reacting to changes in the parent object.
However, I think I might run in some serialization issues with this approach later, for example when trying to expose the structure via a JSON API.

```
public class Garage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Car> ParkedCars { get; set; }
    public List<ParkingLot> ParkingLots { get; set; }
}

public class ParkingLot
{
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public Car(Garage ParentGarage, int LotIndex)
    {
        Garage = ParentGarage;
        AllocatedLot = Garage.ParkingLots[LotIndex];
        Garage.PropertyChanged += Garage_PropertyChanged;
    }
    void Garage_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveToNewLot();
    }
    public ParkingLot AllocatedLot { get; set; }
    private Garage Garage {get;set;}
}
```

In the second approach, I will not tell an individual object about it's parent, therefore the object itself has no way of handling all it's responsibilites, such as reacting to changes in the parent element. The parent element would have to know about it's children and take care of notifying them about changes.

```
public class Garage
{
    public Garage()
    {
        ParkingLots.CollectionChanged += Lot_CollectionChanged;
    }
    public List<Car> ParkedCars { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ParkingLot> ParkingLots { get; set; }
    private void Lot_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Car ParkedCar in ParkedCars)
        {
            ParkedCar.MoveToNewLot(ParkingLot NewLot);
        }
    }
}
public class ParkingLot
{
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Car
{
    public ParkingLot AllocatedLot { get; set; }

    private Garage Garage { get; set; }
}
```

The actual code is similar to some catalogue like object hierarchy, where, for example, renaming of a category will trigger the raising of PropertyChanged events in child objects within that category.

I favor the first approach, since it seems more logical to me to have every object itself being fully responsible for it's own state instead of relying on an "outside" object to ensure a valid state.

My question is, due to a lack of experience, which problem will be more severe, more complicated serialization or having to keep track of object dependencies and violation of the OOP principles?

Is there maybe even another solution I just don't know for how such a structure should be approached?

Comment: You're not really defining a hierarchy, though, are you? That would be an "is-a" relationship. It looks like what you're defining are "has-a" relationships. See: http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php

Comment: The actual code does go deeper, for example, there are objects that implement an IElementContainer interface that can themselves be elements. So my root object is in a "has-a" relationship to its children, but they themselves can both have has-a and is-a relationships.

Comment: Short answer: the data structure should model what actually happens. If a garage moves cars, then put the logic in the parent; if a car moves itself when the garage changes, put the logic in the car. That said, the question is "too broad" at best, especially without firm details regarding your concern related to JSON, and probably is really "primarily opinion based". Either way, not really a good fit for the Stack Overflow model.